# Critical points of a two-variables function

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am stuck in understanding how to proceed about the critical points of this function:
$$f(x, y) = x^2y - xy - x$$

So I did the following:

$$\nabla f = (0, 0) \longrightarrow \begin{cases} 2xy - y = 0 \\ x^2 - x - 1 = 0 \end{cases}$$

The first equation is zero if $y = 0$ or $x = 1/2$.

The second equation is zero for $x = \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$

How shall I proceed from here?

If $y = 0$, the second equation doesn't care of what $y$ is, hence shall I just use the $x$ I found for the second, to complete the points? Like

$$P_1 = \left(\dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, 0\right)$$
$$P_2 = \left(\dfrac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}, 0 \right)$$

What about the point $x = 1/2$ instead? Shall I reject it, for it cannot satisfy the second equation?

Comment: Your definition of $f$ and the pair of equations expressing the components of $\mathbf{\nabla} f = \mathbf{0}$ do not agree.

Comment: But, to answer your question more generally, you are looking for points in the domain where the gradient is the zero vector, which means that each of its components is zero. This is a system of (in this example two) equations. It's possible to satisfy one equation and not the other, in which case you don't have a simultaneous solution to the system of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ only satisfies the first equation and not the second. Thus it will be rejected. So only two critical points that you found: $P_1, P_2$.

Comment: I noticed I also wrote a wrong system of equations... But anyway thank you. I was indeed asking for what to do with the other solution!